# Retrieve RNG seed in julia

Tags: random, julia

In julia, the seed for the global RNG can be set with

```
srand(SEED)
```

How can I retrieve the seed or current state of the global RNG, e.g. again at a later point?

The goal is to get the state of the RNG at any given point in time, and recreate it in a different session, without knowing the initial seed or all calls to RNG that happened in the meanwhile.

For example, R allows access to the current seed through

```
.Random.seed
```

I was hoping that an equivalent way would exist in julia.

Comment: [Read The Fabulous Manual](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/base/#random-numbers).

Comment: @jurgemaister This part refers to setting the seed. I could not find any mentioning on how to get it back.

Comment: @jurgemaister: you don't seem to be understanding the difference between setting the seed and later finding out what the seed was set to.

Comment: @jurgemaister My question does not relate to how set the seed, nor how to generate random numbers.  It is about how to retreive the state of the RNG at a certain point in time, such that I can recreate the same state in a different session.

Comment: Reading questions properly is also important.

Comment: What's the current (Julia 1.7/1.8) way of obtaining the random seed? None of the solutions posted here work: `Random.default_rng().seed` says `type TaskLocalRNG has no field seed`; similarly for `Random.GLOBAL_RNG.seed`; `Random.GLOBAL_SEED` isn't updated after I call `rand()`, so there seems to be more hidden random state.

Answer (score 6):

`Base.Random.RANDOM_SEED` is your friend for getting the seed:

```
julia> srand(10)

julia> Base.Random.RANDOM_SEED
1-element Array{Uint32,1}:
 0x0000000a

julia> srand(1)

julia> Base.Random.RANDOM_SEED
1-element Array{Uint32,1}:
 0x00000001

julia> srand(0xF)

julia> Base.Random.RANDOM_SEED
1-element Array{Uint32,1}:
 0x0000000f
```

This isn't documented, but [the source](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/random.jl) is easy enough to read. I'm not sure how to get the current state of the RNG, but it might be in the [`dSFMT`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/dSFMT.jl) module

Comment: This is now accessible via `Base.Random.GLOBAL_RNG.seed`, instead of `Base.Random.RANDOM_SEED`.

Comment: @Chris, none of this works in Julia 1.7/1.8 anymore: `Base.Random` is now its own package, but `Random.GLOBAL_RNG` has no field `seed` and  `Random.RANDOM_SEED` is not defined

Answer (score 4):

You should get the seed like this

```
reinterpret(Int32, Base.Random.GLOBAL_RNG.seed)
```

Test:

```
julia> srand(123456789);

julia> reinterpret(Int32, Base.Random.GLOBAL_RNG.seed)
1-element Array{Int32,1}:
 123456789
```

For saving an restoring the full rng state you can do the simple thing and just store the whole `Base.Random.GLOBAL_RNG` object. An easy way would be using [JLD](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl) package.

In my private package I do manually save/read the rng state to HDF5, see [here](https://github.com/crstnbr/Helpers.jl/blob/master/src/hdf5.jl#L66-L135).

EDIT: This of course a more explicit version of @IainDunning's answer

Answer (score 2):

Using a specialized MersenneTwister with an explicit variable (instead of the hidden global one provided by the default random values functions), the functionality you require can be provided:

```
newmt = Base.Random.MersenneTwister(123)
randvec = [rand(newmt) for i=1:100]
# save state now
savestate = deepcopy(newmt.state)
randvec2 = [rand(newmt) for i=1:20]
# rewind state to old state
newmt.state = savestate
randvec3 = [rand(newmt) for i=1:20]
if randvec2==randvec3
    println("works!")
end
```

The `deepcopy` threw me off for a second there. Also, it would have been easier to access the global random generator state, but it might require `ccall`ing libdSFMT library (see `random.jl` and `dSFMT.jl` in `Base`.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious solution is to save the seed value before you call `srand(seed)`.

Alternatively, if you know the RNG being used, and it isn't cryptographically secure, then you can calculate the values from the pseudo-random numbers it produces.  For example, see [Cracking a linear congruential generator](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/cracking-a-linear-congruential-generator)

Comment: Random number generation in Julia uses the Mersenne Twister library.

Answer (score 0):

For better control when using a random generator in functions and in general,

```
RND = srand(0)
function coolfun()
    println(RND.idx)
    output = srand(RND, 100)
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answers to this question concern old versions of Julia and don't work any more, I decided to post a new answer.

In Julia version >= 1.0, the field `Base.Random.GLOBAL_RNG` no longer exists.
In Julia 1.0 there is a field `Random.GLOBAL_RNG` in the `Random` package (which is no longer part of `Base`). Retrieving the seed from there and setting it like described in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47900426/3180809 does not work any more.

In Julia 1.4 and 1.5 there is the function `Random.default_rng()`. I managed to get the desired behaviour of saving and reinstating the state of the Random generator with the following code there:

```
julia> import Random

julia> Random.seed!(1);

julia> rand(Int)
6592875438459116351

julia> rng = copy(Random.default_rng());

julia> rand(Int)
1969495256574935408

julia> Random.seed!(2);

julia> rand(Int)
6712802529292398593

julia> copy!(Random.default_rng(), rng);

julia> rand(Int)
1969495256574935408
```

In Julia 1.0, `Random.GLOBAL_RNG` can be used instead of `Random.default_rng()` to get the same result.

I came up with this solution after going through the Julia source code, so I don't know how stable this solution will again be across version.
(The function `Random.default_rng()` is neither exported nor documented.)

I did not succeed in extracting only the seed as a single number that can be used in a call to `Random.seed!` to reinstate a state of a running random number generator. I would also be interested in suggestions or discussions whether this is possible.

Comment: On julia 1.6 `Random.seed!(Random.default_rng().seed)` works, while in julia 1.7 this information is stored in `Random.GLOBAL_SEED`

Comment: The solution I proposed works across versions, also in Julia 1.7.

Comment: @Lufu, `Random.GLOBAL_SEED` isn't updated after I call `rand()`, yet `rand()` produces different output on subsequent calls, which suggests that it's updating some _different_ internal state.

Comment: Thats right, the seed is only used to define the stream(s) of random numbers, which random number is drawn depends on the state of the RNG.

Comment: @Lufu, so how does one obtain the state of the RNG? `Random.default_rng().seed` doesn't work in Julia 1.7 because there's no attribute `seed`

Comment: What do you need it for? You can pass the RNG itself around, copy it or serialize it if you need the same state again.