# Julia - storing random number generator current state (Beta/Gamma) - non "Base" generator

Tags: julia

There has already appeared an answer on stackoverflow on how to save the current state of the "Base" random number generator within Julia (question itself marked as duplicate). However none of the questions or answers are pertinent to random samples from distributions that are set outside the "Base" generator (even though they are used in the main "Distributions" package for Julia). Two such univariate distributions are Gamma and Beta - whose random deviates appear to be created from Distributions package calling a generator from package StatsFuns (which itself appears to rely on an R header/library).

I'm building a patient discrete event simulation model comparing treatments. To reduce monte carlo sampling error/variation between treatments I'd like the ability to save the current state of the random number generator(s) at various points along a patient pathway under one treatment. I can then restore them at appropriate points for the next treatment. Simply setting the seed at the start and resetting it for the same patient under a different treatment does not meet my needs - the stochastic nature will ensure the same patient may follow events in different sequence orders, different scenarios, then possibly converge again later where resetting is needed.

I've inserted Julia programming code that clearly shows my problem - in the first example, saving the random generator state so many iterations in from setting the seed clearly works: outputs "true" for path1 == path3. This example uses Normal distribution. Thanks to Bogumił Kamiński for the function code (borrowed/stole it from his stackoverflow answer [Is there a way to obtain the state of the random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197489/is-there-a-way-to-obtain-the-state-of-the-random-number-generator) ).

But for the code example that uses Gamma distribution, the same function does not work (code prints "false" for final command path1 == path3).

Can anyone please provide an equivalent function similar in spirit to the one listed below but will work for Gamma and Beta random draws (or any alternative suggestions that are not "simply reset manual seed value").

Many thanks (and apologies for long post: thought needed rationale why not duplicate question)

```
using Distributions

function reset_global_rng(rng_state)
 Base.Random.GLOBAL_RNG.seed = rng_state.seed
 Base.Random.GLOBAL_RNG.state = rng_state.state
 Base.Random.GLOBAL_RNG.vals = rng_state.vals
 Base.Random.GLOBAL_RNG.idx = rng_state.idx
end

srand(1234) # set seed
# Now generate 100,000 Normal rands
r = rand(Normal(3,11),10000) 
#Now from herein my model can take two different paths:store generator
rs = deepcopy(Base.Random.GLOBAL_RNG)
# Now take  path 1
path1 = rand(Normal(5,10),2)
# path2 has higher mean but more uncertainty but want to minimise
#monte carlo sampling error, hence desire to reset generator
reset_global_rng(rs)
path2 = rand(Normal(6,12),2)
#To prove the resetting worked do path3 below with same parameters as path1
reset_global_rng(rs)
path3 = rand(Normal(5,10),2)
println(path1==path3) # prints "true"
```

Below does not work correctly for gamma (or beta)

```
srand(1234) # set seed
# Now generate 100,000 Normal rands
r = rand(Normal(3,11),10000) 
#Now from herein my model can take two different paths
# store generator value
rs = deepcopy(Base.Random.GLOBAL_RNG)
# Now take  path 1
path1 = rand(Gamma(5,10),2)
# path2 has higher mean but more uncertainty but want to minimise
#monte carlo sampling error, hence desire to reset generator
reset_global_rng(rs)
path2 = rand(Gamma(6,12),2)
#To prove the resetting hasn't worked:
reset_global_rng(rs)
path3 = rand(Gamma(5,10),2)
println(path1==path3) # prints "false"
```

Comment: The last `println(path1==path3) # prints "false"` prints `true` on my setup (v0.7)

Comment: Also `true` for me (0.6). In fact, `Rmath.jl` [sets the global random generator](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Rmath.jl/blob/master/src/Rmath.jl#L46) of `Rmath-julia` (its C implementation) to Julia's `rand`, which does use `GLOBAL_RNG`.

Comment: Thanks Dan - that's good to know. I'm using the official "stable" release 0.6. I couldn't get 0.7 to work correctly with Distributions on my Windows machine. Looks like if I wait for version 1.0 my problems will be solved (although means waiting indeterminate time - hence not ideal).

Comment: Just seen your later post. I downloaded the juliapro windows option with mkl and run it in Juno/Atom. Are you on Linux with 0.6?

Comment: Jup. v0.6.0 on Ubuntu.

Comment: 0.6 on Ubuntu or Fedora both the same for me too. Have you definitely run the above in a new session?

Comment: Yes I have.  I think it might even be the fact that it is juliapro rather than windows - my packages seem always to be up-to-date since installing few weeks ago - when calling pkg.update function which I doubt and remember reading somewhere that it is suspect with packages..

Comment: I  deinstalled the windows juliopro version and installed the plain v6 REPL and now it all works fine. Thanks for the comments.